# Via Client.Update how to find out that I sent a message?

Tags: telegram-api, wtelegramclient

Tell me how I can understand what is in the handler `Client.Update`. Is the message coming from me?
For some reason, it happens that I look at the `From_id` and `From.Id`, there is my ID, then for some reason, there is not.

As I understand it, it shows my ID when I write in a chat, and if in private messages with a friend, it shows his ID.

I'm trying to catch the ID through a common example.

```
private static void DisplayMessage(MessageBase messageBase, bool edit = false)
{
  if (edit) Console.Write("(Edit): ");

  switch (messageBase)
  {
    case Message m: Console.WriteLine($"{Peer(m.from_id) ?? m.post_author} in {Peer(m.peer_id)}> {m.message}"); break;
    case MessageService ms: Console.WriteLine($"{Peer(ms.from_id)} in {Peer(ms.peer_id)} [{ms.action.GetType().Name[13..]}]"); break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Update event handler has been renamed to `OnUpdate` since this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `message.flags` should contain the flag `Flags.out_` for your outgoing messages.